# jQuery/UI Auto complete but only allow existing words to be typed in

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Hopefully I am explaining this correctly, I have a long predefined list of items (products in my db) and I would like the user to be able to type and auto complete a product, however if that product / word is NOT in the list, I don't want to allow additional characters to be typed.  So the auto complete would ideally block additional input if that input does not exist in the list.

Does something like that exist for the current jQuery UI / jQuery plugin? Or are there mods? I wish to use this method to speed up product selection, but not return a 'not found' page if someone types in something else.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Given your requirement, you probably should be using a dropdown instead of an autocomplete box.  Failing that, you can make an Ajax call to verify the value before posting the page.

Comment: Problem is that a dropdown would be too large and tedious to 'walk through' if I have 2,000 parts for instance...

Comment: Combo boxes autocomplete also (sort of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This AutoComplete plugin](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm) has a function that allows you to test the value to make sure it is in the list.

Comment: I've looked at this plugin, it however does not limit the user from entering something other than what is in the list, I want something that will 'block' additional input.  Otherwise if someone submits the request (for a product) it will return an un-needed not-found forcing the user to either correct or re-type the product.

Comment: I suppose you can call FindValue() on each keystroke. But it's going to be very slow. If a combo box is out, you need to load up the list into the browser beforehand, so that you don't take the hit from the Ajax call on each keystroke. Some custom coding would be required.

Comment: findValue() actually is a great solution and I dump all parts into JS array (a lttle crude) then do a simple if in array check. I got the idea from: http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-autocomplete.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi had a similar problem. Bud did not result to using the dropdown and or the combo box (which, is not fully supported) I decided to use the change event option for the autocomplete like so:

```
jQuery('#field').autocomplete ({
  ...
  source: listOfValues,   // assuming an array like this ['val1', 'val2', val3' ... ]
  change: function (event, ui) {
     // check if entered value exists
     var entered_valid_input = false;   // false until proven true
     jQuery.each(listOfValues, function(i,v) {
       if(jQuery('#field').val() == v) {
         entered_valid_input = true;
         return false;   // stop iterating
       }

     });
     if(!entered_valid_input) {
        // blank the field
        jQuery('#field').val("");
        return;    // exit callback. No further processing
     }

  },
  ...
  // further processing if the input is valid
});
```

Seems to work for me well. Even though it's not the most elegant solution.