# How to fix characters in search autocomplete wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, autocomplete, character

I added a function autocomplete in my wordpress theme and its working to display the titles of posts, but I have some problems with the characters

Search results in autocomplete are like this,

```
Selena Gomez &#8211; Come &#038; Get It
```

instead of this one
Selena Gomez – Come & Get It

My js code is here:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $(function() {
        var url = MyAutocomplete.url + "?action=my_search";
        $( "#s" ).autocomplete({
            source: url,
            delay: 500,
            minLength: 3
        }); 
    });

})( jQuery );
```

and my php  function is this one

```
function add_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' );
    wp_register_style( 'jquery-ui-styles','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-styles' );
    wp_register_script( 'my-autocomplete', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/autocomplete.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' ), '1.0', false );
    wp_localize_script( 'my-autocomplete', 'MyAutocomplete', array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-autocomplete' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' );
function my_search() {
        $term = strtolower( $_GET['term'] );
        $suggestions = array();

        $loop = new WP_Query( 's=' . $term );

        while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            $loop->the_post();
            $suggestion = array();
            $suggestion['label'] = get_the_title();
            $suggestion['link'] = get_permalink();

            $suggestions[] = $suggestion;
        }

        wp_reset_query();


        $response = json_encode( $suggestions );
        echo $response;
        exit();

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_search', 'my_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_search', 'my_search' );
```

where Im wrong can anyone know this issue or how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to find the issue in your question.Can you please highlight or something so that find exact character

Comment: Im sorry I just edited question I added my problem inside code tags, so problem is when I search something the autocomplete works but the charachters like & are different like this one `Selena Gomez &#8211; Come &#038; Get It`

Comment: I just tried to recreate your issue but somehow I am not able to do so. Is there any URL where we can see it live ?

Comment: Thankyou Roli I have it on localhost I added class="autocomplete" in search form it works only if you add the class but as I said I dont know how to add utf8 in that function , I think that I should change something here  ` $term = strtolower( $_GET['term'] );`

Comment: I found also this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018946/jquery-auto-complete-how-do-i-handle-modifications but I couldnt fix it yet I changed the strolower with htmlspecialchars(strtolower($_GET["term"]));

Comment: I don't think you need to change `$term`. I also use auto complete to get published page and I changed one of my page name to `Selena Gomez – Come & Get It` and when I type in my input box, auto complete showing me result as `Selena Gomez – Come & Get It`.

Comment: so thanks for your try I will upload it now in a live host instead of localhost

Comment: If it is live, then many people will find it useful and can help you better and also add jQuery tag :)

Comment: yes Im uploading it now thanks for you help